# Laravel 5.3 custom pagination presenter

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3

anyone know how can I use my own pagination in laravel 5.3? In laravel 5.2 I used this code in my **AppServiceProvider** to rewrite base pagination

```
LengthAwarePaginator::presenter(function($paginator) {
   return new My\Cool\Custom\Pagination($paginator);
});
```

Now on 5.3 there is no more presenters, only views, but this view thing will not work for me as i've rewritten **UrlWindow.php** and **UrlWindowPresenterTrait.php** files of which second file doesn't exist anymore, maybe someone know any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This might be not enough to solve your issue, but if you just need to change the template used to render the pagination:

```
Paginator::$defaultView = 'pagination::bootstrap-4';
Paginator::$defaultSimpleView = 'pagination::simple-bootstrap-4';
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it's not what I needed, I used my custom pagination presenter with fixed bugs and few features which aren't possible to make in custom views.